# Spring boot 2 lombok:jar:2.6.7 is missing, no dependency information available

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, lombok, intellij-lombok-plugin

This is my `pom.xml` it is generated from start.spring.io for M2 spring-boot version. This is why the maven spring repositories are added. But the dependency cant be found .

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0.M2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>auth-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>auth-service</name>
    <description>Authorization service</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.okta.spring</groupId>
            <artifactId>okta-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

When I run `mvn clean:install` from latest Intellij 2019.1.1 I got the following error:

```
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for org.projectlombok:lombok:jar:2.6.7 is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.336 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-04-27T19:04:10+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 18M/70M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project auth-service: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.example:auth-service:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find org.projectlombok:lombok:jar:2.6.7 in http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

Why maven can not get the lombok version correctly? Intellij seems to see the version `2.6.7` because under `Alt+Insert` it is available but then maven can't see it?

Comment: Try `force update` on maven tab and `invalidate caches and restart` in IntelliJ.

Comment: @KorayTugay did not work

Comment: The version 2.6.7 of project lombok does not exist. https://search.maven.org/search?q=org.projectlombok BTW: Do not define versions of yourself. The parent has already done that.

Comment: @khmarbaise 2.6.7 is what intellij gave me. but for 1.18.6 the situation is the same. Also without version  still the problem remains.

Comment: Make sure you are not working in offline mod.

Comment: @KorayTugay I dont think so as the deps are geting downloaded. Can you or enyone replicate this simple pom behaviour with any lmbok annotation?

Comment: Try to build on command line first....if the build is fine then change to IDE...

Comment: Latest lombok version is 1.18.6 (https://projectlombok.org/download) which is why maven fails to download the version 2.6.7 in pom.xml file. Try to remove the version in your pom.xml and build it via command line. i just downloaded a sample spring 2.2.0.M2 project with similar dependencies, it was working fine

Comment: @Sachin Same problem with and without version via Intellij or mvn clean install. Which project did you use that it works as you say?

Comment: You could try a workaround.
IntelliJ has a lombok plugin to install, you can declare the scope of the dependency as provided

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded a similar spring project - 2.2.0.M2 from start.spring.io with similar dependency.
below is my pom.xml file

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0.M2</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>demo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>demo</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.okta.spring</groupId>
        <artifactId>okta-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Did a `mvn clean compile`, could see the dependency being downloaded to my .m2 folder and the build was successful.

Below is a sample Lombok annotation

```
package com.example.demo;

import lombok.Value;

@Value
public class User {
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
}
```

Below is my main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }


    @Override
    public void run(String... args) {
        User user = new User("Hello", "World");
        System.out.println("First Name: " + user.getFirstName());
        System.out.println("Last Name: " + user.getLastName());
        System.out.println(user.toString());
    }

}
```

Below is the output:

```
2019-04-28 10:33:58.649  INFO 8732 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-04-28 10:34:01.069  INFO 8732 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Started DemoApplication in 3.824 seconds (JVM running for 6.822)
First Name: Hello
Last Name: World
User(firstName=Hello, lastName=World)

Process finished with exit code
```

Comment: have you user any lombok annotation like @Value, becouse it is what causes trounble?

Comment: Yes, updated with the lombok annotation and its output. I am using IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1.1 (Community Edition)